# Spring MVC Controller Mapping with Properties Files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to define things externally into Properties files for our annotations on Spring Controllers?

Suppose I have the following Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "processModel.jsp")
public class ProcessorController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayModel() {
         //Code to load processor
         return "processModel";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="submit=Refresh")
    public String refreshModel() {
         //Code to refresh data
         return "processModel";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params="submit=Save Model")
    public String saveModel() {
        //Code to save model
        return "processModel";
    }
}
```

Assume the following HTML is generated:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Model" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Refresh" />
```

It'd be nice to have these params externalized so that we only have to define them once in a properties file.  That way if we need to change the label on a submit button in the JSP, we only need to change it in the properties file, rather than in two places.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotation parameter values need to be a literal or refer to a constant field, so the externalized dynamic value cannot be injected into the @RequestMapping annotation. An alternative may be to drive the behavior using some other hidden form variable mapped to a literal(SAVEMODEL/REFRESH) instead of the text that is displayed to the user(you may get a requirement to internationalize the text displayed to the user at some point and this model will break then)

Answer (score 0):

You may also create a modelAndView methods in your controller and you don't have to put a @requestMapping on the head of the controller. So your controller become something like this:

@Controller

public class ProcessorController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="getView.html" method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayModel(HttpServletRequest request) {
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
     //Code to load processor
     mav.setViewName = "processModel";
     return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="refreshModel.html" method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView refreshModel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
     //Code to refresh data
     mav.setViewName="refreshModel";
     return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="saveModel.html" method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveModel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    //Code to save model
    mav.setViewName="saveModel";
    return mav;
}
```

}

After, you just have to create the three jsp files (saveModel.jsp,refreshModel.jsp,processModel.jsp) and you have 3 views in one controller. And thats all